# Can a virtualbox drive be larger than total free space on HDD?

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to install Windows 10 in a virtualbox within Ubuntu. Unfortunately the total free space I have on my HDD is only ~15 gb. Is this possible to do, given that the windows OS takes up way more space than this?

Comment: You could try initialising the C-drive as compressed, but I have no idea if this will give sufficient performance or enough compression.

Comment: No;  What you want is not possible.  Get a larger HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a dynamic virtual disk to be any size you want and VBox will not stop you.  However, it will behave the same way most applications do when it runs out of disk space: It will crash.

In the case of your situation, you create a virtual HD to be, say, 1TB in size. Fine. The Ubuntu installer will see a 1TB drive.  But if the VHD grows to fill up the entire physical drive, VBox will crash and it will be as if you pulled the power cord during the install.

What you really should be asking is if Ubuntu takes more than ~15GB to install.  That I can't answer.